# While using a For Each loop in VBA, the data gets duplicated multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, duplicates

I am trying to upload the data to the destination workbook from the source workbook.

Let's assume I have 15-20 rows of data.

There are two conditions:

1. When the **`frmData.txtdate.Value` (textbox value from the userform)** is `=` to the **destination workbook's cell value**, then there will be a `MsgBox` displaying that the data is already copied. Also I want that if this gets executed then the destination workbook should get closed.
2. When the **`frmData.txtdate.Value` (textbox value from the userform)** is `=` to the **source workbook's cell value** , then the whole data from range `A2:T999` would get copied and pasted to the destination workbooks range `A:Lastrow`

But when I try doing it, all the 15-20 rows get duplicated and copied for 15-20 times below each other.

The code is as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Upload()
    Dim SourceWB    As Workbook
    Dim SourceWs    As Worksheet
    
    Dim DesWB       As Workbook
    Dim DesWs       As Worksheet
    
    Dim DateRange   As Range
    Dim DesDataRange As Range
    
    Dim LastRowCount As Long        'Upload Button Value
    Dim DesLastRow  As Long
    
    Dim Ls          As Long
    Dim Y           As Long
    
    Set SourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set SourceWs = SourceWB.Worksheets("Database")
    
    Set DesWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Set DesWs = DesWB.ActiveSheet
    
    LastRowCount = SourceWs.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    DesLastRow = DesWs.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set DateRange = SourceWs.Range("D2", "D" & LastRowCount)
    
    Set DesDateRange = DesWs.Range("D2", "D" & DesLastRow)
    
    'Check Destination File for Similar Date
    
    For Each Cell In DesDateRange
        If Cell.Value = frmData.txtdate.Value Then
            
            MsgBox "Data Already Colated, If you want To make any Changes Contact your SME Or Admin"
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
    Next Cell
    
    'Paste Similar Date Values to destination file
    '*The problem starts here*
    
    For Each Cell In DateRange
        If Cell.Value = frmData.txtdate.Value Then
            'Y = Cell.Row            'Cells(y, 1), Cells(y, 20)
            
            SourceWs.Range("A" & 2, "T" & LastRowCount).Copy
            
            Workbooks(FileNameValue).Activate
            
            Ls = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Ls + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues        'AndNumberFormats
            
        End If
    Next
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you're coping the entire range, not just one row: `SourceWs.Range("A" & 2, "T" & LastRowCount).Copy`

Comment: Yes the goal was to copy all data from the described range and paste it over the existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that last for-loop you are:

1. Going through each cell in a column of SourceWS

`For Each Cell In DateRange`

2. Each time copying the whole Source Range

   ```
    If Cell.Value = frmData.txtdate.Value Then
    SourceWs.Range("A" & 2, "T" & LastRowCount).Copy
    Workbooks(FileNameValue).Activate
    Ls = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Ls + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues        'AndNumberFormats
    End If
   ```

Therefore, if more than one cell in DateRange equal the value in txtdate, the whole SourceRange will be copyied (that many times).

So the result you are describing is exactly what is coded.

---

Now if you want to copy the range only once you have two options:

a) Easiest with the code you have: add an `Exit For` within right after pasting the range.

b) Best Practice: instead of the `For each Cell in DateRange` loop, do something like:

```
Dim rn_found
Set rn_found = DateRange.find(frmData.txtdate.Value)
If Not rn_found Is Nothing Then
    '... do your thing
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RichieV, Exit For works perfectly fine. :D Much Appreciated

Comment: HTH, just be sure that this is the behavior you are looking for...it is not what you often see